Random walk probability that walk gets to a before b
I'm having difficulty applying electrical network concepts to solve this exercise. My current approach is setting up a voltage generator from node $p$ to $q$ with $v(p)=1$ and $v(q)=0$, and assigning a current of 0 to the last edge on the right side. However, the lack of symmetry in the graph makes it challenging for me to find a straightforward solution. I suspect I'm introducing more variables than needed. Can someone provide guidance specifically for this graph?
Random walk on graph


These problems are typically solved via states.  Index a state by the nodes.  Work out the system of equations connecting the probabilities you want.

There are only $4$ active nodes, so the linear system can even be solved with paper and pencil.

Fleshing out lulu's comment:
Let $d$ be the top vertex, and let $e$ and $f$ be the bottom two vertices.
For a vertex $s$, let $p_s$ denote the probability of reaching $b$ before $c$ if starting from vertex $s$. We immediately have $p_b=1$ and $p_c=0$.
By conditioning on the first step starting from vertex $s$, we obtain four other equations:
\begin{align}
p_a &= \frac{1}{2} p_d + \frac{1}{2} p_e
\\
p_d &= \frac{1}{3} p_a + \frac{1}{3} p_b + \frac{1}{3} p_c
\\
p_e &= \cdots
\\
p_f &= \cdots
\end{align}
(leaving $p_e$ and $p_f$ for you to do on your own).
In the end you'll have a linear system of $6$ equations (including $p_b=1$ and $p_c=0$) and 6 variables, which you can solve.

Thank you! This method is way easier than the one explained in the notes and lecture - at least for me. I uploaded the wrong picture, but it doesn't matter. I can solve both of them now. If I did it correctly, $a=20/31, d=17/31,e=23/31,f=18/31$
